# How to write two similar django admin actions

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I'd like to customize my django admin actions. My goal is to make a action that could update selected objects, but there is not only one model or one field to be updated. So I guess I should write more than one actions, though these code are quite similar. My question is how to write these actions, considering code reuse.

For example, function update_module(modeladmin, request, queryset) implements a action as below,

```
def update_module(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    ...
    form = module_form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        one = form.cleaned_data['module']
        ...
    ....
admin.site.add_action(update_module)
```

Now I need to write another action as below,

```
def update_src(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    ...
    form = src_form(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        one = form.cleaned_data['src']
        ...
    ....
admin.site.add_action(update_src)
```

As we see, the two actions are quite similar. Is there some methods to reuse more code. Maybe decorator should be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I haven't tested this, but I think it should work.

```
def update_func(model):
    def update(modeladmin, request, queryset):
        ...
        form = module_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            one = form.cleaned_data[model]
            ...
        ...
    return update
admin.site.add_action(update_func('module'))
admin.site.add_action(update_func('src'))
```

Comment: It's possible you may get all the necessary per-model parameters from modeladmin, so there'll might be no need to make a closure, and you could get everything through `modeladmin` argument.